# I would like to filter data in a DataGridView using a DataView

Tags: c#, datagridview, dataview, rowfilter

I tried the code below, but it does not work. What's wrong?

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // DataView component
    DataView view = new DataView();
    view.Table = database1DataSet1.Tables["sample"];
    view.RowFilter = "surname LIKE '%" + textBox1.Text + "%'";
}
```

Comment: I think you need to elaborate on what does not work. do you get an error? does it not get filtered? what actually happens when you run this code?

Comment: Are you setting the `DataView` as the source?

Comment: No errors. It does not filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you need to add the following line after setting the view.RowFilter:

```
DataGridView1.DataSource = view;
```